# In a push-pull twin, which engine is number one?

Tags: terminology, multi-engine

I know this is kind of a silly question, but I'm curious.

On a "standard" multi-engine airplane, the engines are numbered from port to starboard, with the furthest port engine being number one. But in a "push-pull" twin-engine airplane like the Cessna Skymaster, which engine is considered "number one"?

Comment: @757toga Well, who decided that the left engine is always "#1" in a conventional plane?

Comment: Probably some pilot or engineer from the early days who's name is forever lost to the sands of time...

Comment: With the port/starboard engine numbering, if they had copied ship numbering schemes we'd have even numbers on the left and odds on the right, just to really confuse people.

Comment: @757toga Listening to ATC recordings on YouTube and LiveATC, I've heard them refer to engines by number, even on twin-engine Boeings. They will usually clarify by saying something like "We're having trouble with engine number one; the left-hand engine".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Cessna didn't designate them as #1 and #2, then there isn't one.

The convention Boeing uses is Left-to-Right and Front-to-Rear for numbering: the left engine is the #1, the forward doors to the aircraft are the #1 (1L and 1R) doors, and things work toward the rear from there (2L and 2R, then 3L and 3R, and so on).  And obviously seating rows start with #1 in the front and get ever higher numbers toward the rear.

So by ***that*** convention, the forward engine would be the #1, which would probably be intuitive to most people.

Interestingly, Lockheed used the same front-to-rear convention for numbering the guns on the AC-130, where the #1 and #2 were the twin 20mm cannons up front, and stepping up to higher numbers working toward the rear.  In the AC-130U, which didn't have twin 20's but a single gatling gun up front, that gun was the #1, the 40mm was the #2, and the 105mm was the #3; in the older AC-130H I *think* they didn't renumber things as the small gatling guns were removed, so I think they still referred to their 105 as the #7 gun, even though there weren't 6 guns installed forward of it.  I assume that the AC-130J uses the same convention, but I'm not familiar enough with those to state anything definitively there.

Comment: Good answer., but at least in the B737 ck list it normally refers to engine #1 and engine #2 (when starting for example). The C337 ck list only refers to "front," "rear," and "affected" engines.

Comment: @757toga  Yeah, thus my ***first*** sentence -- if Cessna didn't designate a #1 or #2 engine, then there isn't one, period - dot - full stop.  Everything after that is just what-if-ing and "if you were to apply the Boeing or Lockheed conventions to this Cessna, here's the result you'd end up with."  Not suggesting that there's a reason **to** apply those conventions there.

Answer (score 1):

In this [1971 Cessna 337 Skymaster](https://jasonblair.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Cessna-1971-Super-Skymaster-337-POH.pdf) (push-pull twin-engine airplane) Owner's Manual the engines are referred to as the **front, rear or affected**, depending on what section of the manual you are reading.

I'm unaware of a specific, universally accepted designation, that identifies a Skymaster's engines (push-pull twin-engine airplane) as "number one" or "number two."